# What circumstances would necessitate an international "Supernatural Police" organisation?

Tags: government, military-defense, security

Some background on this question, I was trying to construct an international organisation whose main job is to patrol, investigate and protect its member countries from anomalous threats that have been regularly popping up. These threats can range from a simple humanoid abomination terrorizing a handful of people to an enormous eldritch abomination who could destroy entire cities.

My initial reasoning for it being an international organisation instead of just the individual countries enacting their own organisation is because some of these anomalies are capable of organizing themselves into a multinational threat which might necessitate cooperation between numerous countries within the region.

However I wonder if this could be rendered redundant by any simple changes within an existing government organisation or by simple cooperation between different government organisation.

So I ask you this is there any specific conditions that would necessitate an international organisation to form that patrols its member countries and cause them to work together in order to handle the occurrence of anomalous events?

Comment: Ever heard of the [Global Occult Coalition](http://www.scp-wiki.net/groups-of-interest#toc10)? Looks pretty much like the organization you're talking about.

Comment: @ForNeVeR To a lesser extent, the SCP Foundation itself as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you make a SECRET international organization, it would be far easier than having the backing of multiple countries. It would be a lot of red tape, many years, and quite a few arguments to get something like that off the ground. Even if it was successful there would likely still be different restrictions in each country. Likely couldn't get all of the countries in on it either, but that's good conflict.

If the scope of your story allows for years to be there for negotiations to complete then you're set. They could be sped along by the gravity of the threat, but at the same time, you have to consider how capable this team is. Is it a team that was previously working in the shadows and can come out in an instant and say 'hey, give us permission and we can help' or will it be people who were previously ignorant rushing to garner control of the situation.

The former lends your group more power in the situation, the latter and a great number of politicians would likely fight against the change. Essentially: What can these people do that my police can't?

You'll have to remember that it's not just policy that would be at odds in a situation like this as well, but public opinion. A politician might know something is the right or smart thing to do, but if their entire country is against working with X, Y, or Z they could still be swayed otherwise. Worldwide agreements are complicated beasts without the proper motivation to fix them and fast.

Your MOST LIKELY scenario would be individual groups in each country along with an overarching group that helps them communicate and mobilize across the globe. That way, each country gets to do things their way, but when the danger crosses borders there are people available who can quickly and effectively navigate the red tape as well as assist with problems such as language, culture, and travel. It would still be a balancing act. As simply as possible, each country would have to feel in control and simply gaining positive support by being a part of this network. If they feel manipulated or controlled tensions would most likely rise up again.

Comment: *"Individual groups in each country along with an overarching group that helps them communicate and mobilize across the globe"* -- isn't this exactly what [Interpol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpol) is? Or, if national security is felt to be at danger, NATO? Anyway, +1 for highlighting why a coordination organization is much more plausible than an executive organization.

Comment: Thanks for the input. To answer some of your questions, yes this takes place after all the negotiations and dealings are done and the story starts somewhere at the very beginning of the organisation history also I would say that the advantage of this over the conventional police would be a dedicated facility and management towards dealing with the anomalous threats. Also would you say that the idea of the organisation  being split into different branches based on their countries would be acceptable?

Comment: Ah yes, Interpol! That would be a good reference and plenty of real-world scenarios. I would say that different branches would be almost required. To mobilize quickly enough you would need people all over the world and each of those units would likely be tailored to the individual culture or needs of the area. For instance, somewhere like Italy may need to be more prepared for aquatic events versus somewhere like Nigeria. Each branch would have its own way of most effectively monitoring the situation and be a part of a grander organization that can move resources and agents as threats change.

Answer (score 4):

Excerpted from the [Constitution of the WHO](http://www.who.int/about/mission/en/) (World Health Organization).

> - The health of all peoples is fundamental to the attainment of peace    and security and is dependent on the fullest co-operation of individuals and States.
> - The achievement of any State in the promotion    and protection of health is of value to all.
> - Unequal development in different countries in the promotion of health and control of diseases, especially communicable disease, is a
>     common danger.

The rationale for the WHO is the same as the rationale for your organization.  A paranormal threat might establish itself and strengthen in a region of the world where the financial and institutional resources to combat it do not exist.  As stated, these circumstances pose\ a "common danger" to all the peoples of the world.

Your organization can be an arm of the WHO.  It may or may not want to proclaim itself as an arm dedicated to fighting paranormal threats, depending on how up front about the existence of these threats the powers are in your world.  WHO is great cover.  It is already an international organization and already tasked with going to remote corners of the world to keep humanity safe, and for decades has been recognized by foreign governments as an entity dedicated to that task.

Also the WHO already has a sweet and swanky headquarters in Geneva.  This proposed expansion can house your paranormal defense branch.

[image]

from [archdaily.com](http://www.archdaily.com/770287/paolo-venturella-proposes-plus-is-more-for-who-headquarters-extension/55a59cbbe58ece562e000068-paolo-venturella-proposes-plus-is-more-for-who-headquarters-extension-image)  That is me in the foreground in case you were wondering.

Comment: My apologies but this does not fit within the requirements of the organisation I had in mind. Due to the nature of these threats the organisation must make itself known so as to spread awareness to the people so that they can report on any anomalous circumstances to the organisation. Also most of the time significant firepower would often be required as the type of threat they face tend to necessitate it e.g. a zombie outbreak, a giant monster rampaging in a city or a humanoid abomination taking a lot of lives.

Comment: /It may or may not want to proclaim itself/.  A branch of the WHO does not have to be secret.  The WHO is not at all secret and so the default path would be that any branch would not be secret either.

Answer (score 2):

Well, [INTERPOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpol) is a normal world (non paranormal) "intergovernmental organization facilitating international police cooperation".  You could borrow from it its primary premise and adjust to paranormal affairs.  Looks credible to me.  Indeed, there was some thing similar by the middle ages controlled by Roman Church.  They had a handbook/manual you can find today: [Malleus Maleficarum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleus_Maleficarum).